# PS script to bookmark URL in IE

Tags: powershell

I have written a PS script which will create bookmarks in IE. I need to execute below command before running the ps script.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -force
```

How can I avoid executing above cmd before executing ps script? Or Can anyone suggest me to convert this as .exe or .bat file?

And this script fails if Favourites folder doesn't exist and how can I avoid using favourites folder in this script.

My PS script:-

```
function create-bookmarks{                  
    $bookmarks = @{ 
    "folder1" = @{
        "Jenkins" = "https://jenkins.net";
    };
    "folder2" = @{  
        "Jenkins" = "https://jenkins.net";
    };
}
    foreach ($Name in $bookmarks.keys)
    {
        $IEFav =  [Environment]::GetFolderPath('Favorites','None')                  
        New-Item $IEFav\$Name -ItemType Directory -Force
        $Shell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
        $IEFav = Join-Path -Path $IEFav -ChildPath $Name
        foreach ($key in $bookmarks[$Name].keys)
        {
            $FullPath = Join-Path -Path $IEFav -ChildPath "$($key).url"
            $shortcut = $Shell.CreateShortcut($FullPath)
            $shortcut.TargetPath = $bookmarks[$Name][$key]
            $shortcut.Save()
        }
    }   
}
create-bookmarks
```

Error if Favourite folder does not exists under c:/users/username/Favourites.

```
PS C:\Users\username\downloads\Bookmarks> .\Bookmarks.ps1
Cannot find an overload for "GetFolderPath" and the argument count: "2".
At C:\Users\username\downloads\Bookmarks\Bookmarks.ps1:27 char:45
+                         $IEFav =  [Environment]::GetFolderPath <<<< ('Favorites','None')
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest



    Directory: C:\


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----         8/22/2018   6:44 PM            DevOps
Join-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At C:\Users\username\downloads\Bookmarks\Bookmarks.ps1:30 char:31
+                         $IEFav = Join-Path -Path <<<<  $IEFav -ChildPath $Name
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Join-Path], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.JoinPathCom
   mand
```

Comment: The error message says the `[Environment]::GetFolderPath()` function needs just **one** parameter, not two, so drop the `'None'` and make it `$IEFav =  [Environment]::GetFolderPath('Favorites')`

Comment: Also, test what you get with `$FullPath = Join-Path -Path $IEFav -ChildPath "$($key).url"`. There is no element called `url` in the hash you create.

Comment: I ran the script and it went fine. Note that i was running it on a elevated powershell console

Comment: @Theo.. Thank you... By removing the value, error has gone